# direct sums with different dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Is it possible for two subspaces of a different dimension to have a direct sum?

For example the vectorspace ${R}$ [X]<3 with the subspaces U=${R}$ [X]<1 and W={a+aX+bX^2+bX^3|a,b $\in$ ${R}$}.

Comment: Do you see any reason why the answer would be no?

Comment: No, but i also don't see a reason why the answer would be yes.

Comment: But... the definition of direct sum obviously doesn't demand that the subspaces have the same dimension, so it just seems strange to me why you would even want to apply this limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider, as you said $V = \def\R{\mathbf R}\R[X]_{\le 3}$, with the subspaces

> $U = \R[X]_{\le 1}$, and $W = \{a+aX + bX^2 + bX^3: a,b\in \mathbf R\}$.

This sum is not direct, as $1 + X \in U \cap W$.

But there are direct sums of spaces with different dimensions:

> $U = \R[X]_{\le 2}$ and $W = \{aX^3: a \in \R\}$.

Then $V = U \oplus W$: For $p = a+bX+cX^2+dX^3\in V$, we have 
$$ p = (a+bX+cX^2) + dX^3 \in U + W $$
On the other hand if $p=a+bX+cX^2+dX^3 \in U \cap W$, we have $d = 0$ due to $p \in U$ and $a=b=c = 0$ due to $p \in W$. Hence $p = 0$.

So, this sum is direct, but $\dim U = 3$, $\dim W = 1$. As allways for direct sums, we have 
$$ \dim(U \oplus W) = \dim U + \dim W = 3+ 1 = 4. $$

Comment: Thank you! It's all much clearer now!